# How can I get a class to print out a string variable from an arraylist of objects located in another class?

Tags: java

With this I can print the list of names of each object within that class, but I'd like to be able to call the variables in a method in the tournament class and then in the GameUI, print that method containing the variable names depending on user input.

```
public class Reserve {
private List<Dragon> dragonReserve;
private List<Wizard> wizardReserve;
private List<Warrior> warriorReserve;
//private List<Champions> champions;

public Reserve() {
    wizardReserve = new ArrayList<>();
    dragonReserve = new ArrayList<>();
    warriorReserve = new ArrayList<>();
    //champions = new ArrayList<>();

    wizardReserve.add(new Wizard("Ganfrank", 7, true, "transmutation"));
    wizardReserve.add(new Wizard("Rudolf", 6, true, "invisibility"));
    wizardReserve.add(new Wizard("Neon", 2, false, "translocation"));

    warriorReserve.add(new Warrior("Elblond", 1, 150, "sword"));
    warriorReserve.add(new Warrior("Flimsi", 2, 200, "bow"));
    warriorReserve.add(new Warrior("Argon", 9, 900, "mace"));

    dragonReserve.add(new Dragon("Drabina", 7, false));
    dragonReserve.add(new Dragon("Golum  ", 7, true));
    dragonReserve.add(new Dragon("Xenon  ", 7, true));
}

public List<Dragon> getDragonReserve() {
    return dragonReserve;
}
public List<Wizard> getWizardReserve() {
    return wizardReserve;
}
public List<Warrior> getWarriorReserve() {
    return warriorReserve;
}
```

}

```
public class GameUI {

    private static Scanner myIn = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice;
        String playerName;
        String output = "";
        int result = -1;
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter player's name");
            String s = myIn.nextLine();
            //myIn.nextLine();
            choice = 100;
            while (choice != 0) {
                choice = getMenuItem();
                if (choice == 1) {
             tr.getReserve().getDragonReserve().forEach(System.out::println);
tr.getReserve().getWizardReserve().forEach(System.out::println);
tr.getReserve().getWarriorReserve().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

```
public class Tournament implements TOC 
{

public String getReserve() {
         Reserve reserve = new Reserve();
         return reserve;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not fully understand what you want, but I think this will solve your problem.

The Reserve class.

```
public class Reserve {
    private List<Dragon> dragonReserve;
    ...

    public Reserve() {
        dragonReserve = new ArrayList<>();
        dragonReserve.add(new Dragon("Drabina", 7, false));
        ...
    }

    public List<Dragon> getDragonReserve() {
        return dragonReserve;
    }
    ...
}
```

The GameUI class.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tournament tournament = new Tournament();
        ...
        if (choice == 1) {
 tournament.getReserve().getDragonReserve().forEach(System.out::println);
        }
        ...
    }
```

The Tournament class.

```
public class Tournament implements TOC {

public Reserve getReserve() {
         Reserve reserve = new Reserve();
         return reserve;
    }
}
```

Also you can override the toString() function in your object.

Comment: I have another class called Tournament which contains a method called getReserve() {} I want to compile the arraylist of objects in there and then in the GameUI class I use System.out.println(tr.getReserve()); to print the list of champions in the reserve.

Comment: In side the Tournament.getReserve(), create a Reserve object (Reserve rsv = new Reserve();) and return back (return rsv;). Then, in GameUI just write "tr.getReserve().getDragonReserver().forEach(System.out::println);"

Comment: I tried this but it states that reserve cannot be converted into a string. What would be the Variable if not string? I can't use void because I need it to return reserve right?

Comment: The Reserve contains you list of objects. If I understand you correctly you don't want to print reserve, you want to print the lists which inside the reserve. Right?

Comment: I want to print the object's string name only within the list.

Comment: For example, for the dragons, it has (name "Drabina", int 7, boolean false) and same for the other objects, I want to be able to print just Drabina Golum Xenon etc using the method in tournament to retrieve those variables from that object list as a string and then use this in gameUI to print this

Comment: You need to change getReserve function return type to Reserve in Tournament class. Also, in your Objects (Wizard, Warrior and Dragon) override the toString() function and just return what you want to write. Also, in GameUI you need to create Tournament like > "Tournament tr = new Tournament();", then you can call tr.getReserve......